# Distinguish sends made by list and by data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, history-tracking

I import "My Tracking Data" using PHP Fuel SDK in this way:

```
require('ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();

$objectType = "Send"; 
$getResponse = new ET_Get($myclient, $objectType, $sendProps, $sendFilter); 

echo($getResponse);
```

All seems OK, but i want to distinguish sends made by list and by data extensions.

See an example #1 (send by list):

[image]

See an example #2 (send by data extension):
[image]

Code shown above doesnot give me posibility to differ lists and data extension (no such field in $getResponse -> results).

Can anyone help me to find the difference between send by list and send by data extension?

Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Regards, Alex.

Comment: is this related to Salesforce? If not, please post your question on Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explanation. Will follow your advice.