# Retrieving Data Extension names used in a Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I have an email send definition that's configured to send to multiple data extensions.  I've seen a few posts ([here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42043/retrieving-data-extension-used-to-filter-e-mail-send), [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42043/retrieving-data-extension-used-to-filter-e-mail-send) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/distinguish-sends-made-by-list-and-by-data-extension)) that say retrieving the Names or CustomerKeys of these data extensions isn't possible using the SOAP API.

However, when I retrieve the [ListSend](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listsend/) object for a particular send, I (surprisingly) see a [List](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/list/) object for each of the Data Extensions.

Is there any way to map these back to API retrievable objects?

```
List.ID:  429   List.ListName:  All Subscribers
List.ID:  5036  List.ListName:  VPL 5036 for List 429
List.ID:  5037  List.ListName:  VPL 5037 for List 429
List.ID:  5038  List.ListName:  VPL 5038 for List 429
List.ID:  5039  List.ListName:  VPL 5039 for List 429
```

Comment: I know you're definitely on the "power-user" end of the spectrum so I assume you know about send logging... can you comment on why that won't work for you?

Comment: Technically it will work, but an API solution would be much less disruptive.  First, you can't enforce sendlogging for every send (as far as I know).  Also, it only covers sends from the point it's been enabled, so we can't pull historical data.  Plus, you'd need to add scripting to every email, which can be problematic if the client is building their own emails.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs did you manage to solve this? I've been 3 days trying to connect JobID to Data Extensions with no luck :( I think it's simply not possible, even though in the UI you can easily see it in Tracking section. Really disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your only option is to match by name here:

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Description</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>Name</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>TestSendRecipient</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: The lists above appear to be temporary, since they mirror the DE's used in the send audience.  I haven't been able to retrieve them by ID or by name.

Comment: Strange. Not sure there is any other way to get it back then without send logging...

Comment: For the historical data, you will need to enlist the help of a Data Architect by purchasing a services engagement.