# Retrieve DataExtensions associated with Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to use the API to retrieve the data extensions that are associated with an email send. So far I have tried using the ListSend object, which returns some useful information but I'm not sure how to connect the results of ListSend to the actual DataExtension.

As an example, below is the output I get after retrieve ListSend (python). You can see here that for the send I am retrieving there are 2 ListSend objects, and each has an associated List object. The Name of the list (VPL 3354 for List 149) does not correlate to anything in our account. So, how do I use this data to retrieve the associated DataExtension?

In the [documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listsend/) it says:

> If you conducted the send to a data extension, ListSend represents any associated publication lists.

I'm not sure what to do with this information.

Here is the example retrieval of ListSend:

```
  (ListSend){
     PartnerKey = None
     ObjectID = None
     List = 
        (List){
           PartnerKey = None
           ID = 3354
           ObjectID = None
           ListName = "VPL 3354 for List 149"
        }
     UniqueClicks = 0
     UniqueOpens = 1
     NumberSent = 1
     NumberDelivered = 1
     Unsubscribes = 0
  },
  (ListSend){
     PartnerKey = None
     ObjectID = None
     List = 
        (List){
           PartnerKey = None
           ID = 3357
           ObjectID = None
           ListName = "VPL 3357 for List 149"
        }
     UniqueClicks = 8789
     UniqueOpens = 25565
     NumberSent = 111323
     NumberDelivered = 109638
     Unsubscribes = 39
  },
```

Comment: Related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61521/retrieving-data-extension-names-used-in-a-send

Comment: I guess I am not the only one trying to do this. It doesn't look like there is a solution either. Bummer.

Comment: I don't believe that property is exposed anywhere in the API.